# How can I use a Generics with inheritance in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

I am trying to understand Generics here and am struggling. I have a simple code that looks like

```
interface A {
    
}

interface B {
    
}

class C : A, B {
    
}

fun <T: A> changeVal() : T {
    return C()
}
```

And I get the following error `Type mismatch: inferred type is C but T was expected`. What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've written a function that says "Name me a subclass of `A`. I'll return an instance of that subclass." This signature is a lie, since you always return `C()`, which is a `C` instance, not a `T` for all `T` subclasses of `A`.

Generics establish a "for all" relationship. The caller is always the one who decides what the generic instantiates to, not the callee. In your case, you simply want to return `A`.

```
fun changeVal() : A
```

The feature you're *trying* to use is called existential typing, and it's not something that's available in Kotlin. In Haskell (with appropriate compiler extensions), the signature might look something like

```
data AContainer where
  AVal :: forall a. a -> AContainer

changeVal :: AContainer
changeVal = ...
```

but Kotlin does not have this feature. In fact, this is exactly what subtyping in an OOP language is meant to do: it says "I have an object that has these features, but I don't know anything concrete about it". So you don't need generics to express this pattern.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation!

Comment: Someone asks a question about Kotlin and you give an answer in... *checks notes* HASKELL???